# Accessible problems on classical groups over complex or real numbers.

Tags: gr.group-theory

I am a undergraduate student doing project with my professor in group theory. I am Looking for some accessible problems for undergraduate on Classical groups over complex or real numbers (particularly symplectic groups).

Comment: I wish you luck with your project, but your request is not really on topic for this site; please see the FAQ.  It would be better to ask at math.stackexchange.com, where I am sure people will be happy to help.

Comment: Usually, in undergraduate research, coming up with problems is part of the professor's job, not the student's.

Comment: @Neil Strickland I do not think it would be more suitable for math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Classical groups are really a classical topic and have been studied a lot. It is therefore not easy to find some interesting topics which are still accessible. Certainly there are some aspects of unitary representations of classical groups, which are interesting but also not too technical. Also, studying Clifford algebras and classical groups is an accessible topic.
An active field is also the geometry and algebra of classical groups over finite fields - but
you wanted real or complex numbers.

Finally, I agree with the comments that there should be advice for you from your supervisors,
which certainly know much better than me what topics are suitable.